# convert byte array to strings split by NUL character

Tags: c#, arrays, split, unicode-string

I am sorry, if this is much of a dumb question. But I can't really figure this out, and I bet it has to be much simpler than I think.

I have a `byte[]` array which contains several Unicode Strings, each char takes clearly 2 bytes, and each string is delimited by two 00 00 bytes, until double 00 00 marks the end of it all.

When I try to use `UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(myBuffer)` I do get the first string, but when the delimiter byte is found it start to get garbage all around.

Right now I am parsing byte by byte and then concatenating things but I am sure there has to be a better way into this.

I was wondering if I should try to find the "position" of the delimiter bytes and then limit the `GetString` method to that lent? But if so, how do you find 2 the position of 2 specific bytes in a byte array?

the example byte array looks like this:

```
Hex View
 
00000000  73 00 74 00 72 00 31 00  00 00 73 00 74 00 72 00  s.t.r.1...s.t.r.
00000010  32 00 00 00 73 00 74 00  72 00 33 00 00 00 00 00  2...s.t.r.3.....
```

Comment: @R.M.Reza Considering this question is for C# and has nothing to do with arrays, no, certainly not.

Comment: Do you reckon that posting your code might be helpful?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Sorry I accidentally pressed the button. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your buffer is valid little endian UTF-16 data. Those "double 00 bytes" is just the NUL character, or `\0`.

`Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myBuffer)` will actually correctly decode the whole buffer, but it'll have embedded NUL characters in it delimiting each sub string. Which is fine, because `\0` is just like any character. This isn't C.

The sample code below will use `Console.WriteLine` to signify "use the substring", but feel free to substitute with what is appropriate.

#### First approach: decode the whole thing

If you split by `\0` after decoding, you can get all the substrings, removing empty entries to get rid of those final NULs:

```
var decoded = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myBuffer);
foreach(var str in decoded.Split('\0', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Alternatively, you can search for the first NUL if you want:

```
var index = decoded.IndexOf('\0');
var firstStr = decoded.Substring(0, index);
```

#### Second approach: split, then decode

If you don't want to do it all in one go because you have to process a lot of data at once, then you could just find the next `0 0` byte sequence, and then decode from there:

```
var toFindSpan = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes("\0".AsSpan());
var units = myBuffer.AsSpan();
while (!units.IsEmpty)
{
    var index = units.IndexOf(toFindSpan);
    if (index == -1)
        break;

    if (index > 0)
    {
        var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(units[..index]);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    units = units[(index + toFindSpan.Length + 1)..];
}
```

Alternatively, cast to a span of `char`, which would allow you to use `ToString()` on the span to get a string, skipping the decoding step, but this assumes the data is all valid text (as ultimately, all you're doing is skipping the validation). Up to you.

#### Third approach: reading from a stream, character by character

But then if you have that much data on hand you probably should be reading from a stream, using a `StreamReader` to decode on the go:

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream(myBuffer, false);
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
    
var current = new StringBuilder();
int c;
while((c = reader.Read()) != -1)
{
    if (c == 0)
    {
        if(current.Length > 0)
        {
            var str = current.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            current.Clear();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        current.Append((char)c);
    }
}
```

#### Fourth approach: reading from a stream in batches

An optimisation to the code above would be to call `Read` with a block of chars and then piece the data back yourself:

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream(myBuffer, false);
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
    
Span<char> batch = stackalloc char[4096];
    
var current = new StringBuilder();
int read;
while ((read = reader.Read(batch)) > 0)
{
    var left = batch[..read];
    while (!left.IsEmpty)
    {
        var index = left.IndexOf('\0');
        if (index == -1)
        {
            current.Append(left);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            current.Append(left[..index]);
            
            // we have a string, collect it
            var str = current.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(str);

            current.Clear();
                
            left = left[(index + 1)..];
        }
    }
}
    
if(current.Length > 0)
{
    // don't forget letfovers
    var str = current.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

That should get you decent results.

Now, those two final approaches use a `StringBuilder` to build the substrings, but you don't have to do it that way, you can send those characters elsewhere (maybe you're writing them to a file).

Comment: Oh wow, you are correct, I knew it was something I wasn't seeing properly . that is perfect.
However, I am decoding like 500k of bytes when I'm sure the strings are only on the first 10k until a double \0 is found, How can I limit the decoding so I don't decode the whole 500k bytes?

Comment: Sure, I put some more ideas.

Comment: That's is wonderful, thanks a lot for taking the time to explain all  possible solutions, so kind ! now it all makes sense.

Comment: The reason I asked about not decoding it all was not to make it that complex, or to do it on batches, I can certainly decode the whole byte buffer, but I KNOW that it has a lot more data than I need, all I want is the substring of the byte array per se that start from 0 to the first occurrence of a double \0  , all the rest is just garbage.

but I guess I wont notice a lot of a difference by running Unicode.GetString on 500k vs just 10k of bytes. less than ms...

Comment: Ultimately, it's mostly an issue of memory, not speed. 500 KB will go on the large object heap, which means memory fragmentation and other problems.

Comment: Right, once again, good point, I will try to split the original array by \0\0 and use just the first part

Comment: @Charlieface Good point, I incorporated that in the answer.